# interrupt animation by touch using UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan, uiviewpropertyanimator

I'm trying to control the animation by screen touch

when i touches screen then view's alpha goes 0

but if touches again while alpha is changing to 0

then alpha goes 1 again (interrupt animation which make alpha value 0)

so i write

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

var showAnimation:UIViewPropertyAnimator!
var hideAnimation:UIViewPropertyAnimator!
var isHiding:Bool = false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue

    showAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1
    })
    hideAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0
    })
    showAnimation.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    showAnimation.isInterruptible = true
    hideAnimation.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    hideAnimation.isInterruptible = true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isHiding = !isHiding
    if self.isHiding {
        self.hideAnimation.startAnimation()
        self.showAnimation.stopAnimation(true)
    }else{
        self.hideAnimation.stopAnimation(true)
        self.showAnimation.startAnimation()
    }
}
}
```

but touchesBegan called only after animation blocks are finished

how can i solve this problem

Comment: Did you try using `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of touchesBegan?

Comment: it's same! but if don't set the alpha to 0, i think it's work
i set the alpha to 0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to know here:

- You don't need to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` and `isInterruptible` to true after initializing `UIViewPropertyAnimator` because their default values are true.
- After calling `stopAnimation`, `UIViewPropertyAnimator` will become invalid and you can't call `startAnimation` to make it work again. So you need to reinitialize `showAnimation` and `hideAnimation` after stop them.

To resolve problem, try my code below.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  var showAnimation:UIViewPropertyAnimator!
  var hideAnimation:UIViewPropertyAnimator!
  var isHiding:Bool = false
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isHiding = !isHiding
    if self.isHiding {
      self.showAnimation?.stopAnimation(true)

      self.hideAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0.1
      })
      self.hideAnimation.startAnimation()
    }else{
      self.hideAnimation?.stopAnimation(true)

      self.showAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1
      })
      self.showAnimation.startAnimation()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thanks a lot!! I didn't catch that i should initialize animation objects